# Highlight the corresponding y axis on mouse overr over the bar chart based on that axis in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

The process what i am working on it to highlight the y axis , when move the mouse over the barchart which is created based on the y axis.

I have got the ways to make the x axis change color based on the "Bold X-Axis Label on Point Hover in Highcharts Column Chart" but cannot able to apply this to get the y axis change color or make it highlighted.

In the current fiddle i have applied to change the color of the y axis, but cannot remove the color when i move the mouse from the series in the chart which is based on that y axis.

Thanks in Advance.

```
jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X2t9H/
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code of what have you tried so far !

Comment: Have added the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X2t9H/ , on mouse over implemented the process to change color for the axis title, now applied for temperatue[axis]

Comment: So it looks like work properly, am I wrong?

Comment: @SebastianBochan have made it work when i mouse over it, but cannot revert it when i move mouse out of it.

Comment: Why you cannot use update() again on mouseover? http://jsfiddle.net/X2t9H/2/ (set correct colour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do that the same as you did the title color change:

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
    title: {
        style: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    },
    lineColor: 'red',
    lineWidth: 1
});
```

EDIT - 
To revert the color do this:

```
mouseOut: function () {
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            title: {
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        });
}
```

You had the `mouseOut` function in there but you didn't populate it.

Comment: Hi wergeld, thanks for your help, but what i want is to remove the color when i move the mouse out of it. ie change color when mouse over it and revert it when mouse is out of the series

Comment: Hi wergeld, is there a way to achieve this on hover over the respective series ,ie on barchart or line chart to make the corresponding y axis, change color.

Comment: @logan I am confused - this what this does.

Comment: Hi wergeld, the problem is when i use mouseover and mouseout, due to the large content in my graph, it takes time to change the color. That the reason i what to achieve this on hover(like tooltip).